# List available Android resource packages at runtime?

Tags: android, android-resources

[Resources.getIdentifier(String,String,String)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#getIdentifier%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) requires the resource package. Unfortunately, if the APK was built with `aapt`'s `--rename-manifest-package` option, the resource package won't be the same as the package returned from [Context.getPackageName()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getPackageName%28%29). For instance, if `AndroidManifest.xml` has the following:

```
<manifest package="foo.bar" ...>
...
</manifest>
```

but `aapt` is run with `--rename-manifest-package foo.bar.baz`, then the APK's resources will have the package name `foo.bar` while `Context.getPackageName()` will return `foo.bar.baz`. Thus, calls to `Resources.getIdentifier(String,String,String)` will return `0` whenever the package name from `Context.getPackageName()` is used.

How can I get a list of the available resource packages in the APK so I can search them for my resource identifier?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/adt-dev/cqdjG2TuM-I

from Xavier Ducrohet:

> They make the assumption that the package name of the app is the same
>   as the R class. This really is not correct. While the previous build
>   system somewhat implied this, aapt always had the feature to generate
>   the R class in a different package.
>
> Thinking about it there really is no current way to query the app for
>   the package of the R class. It'd have to be provided to the library.

Basically, there is no way to do it. The package name would have to be passed to the library explicitly.

You can automate passing the package name by [using a dummy R file](http://www.piwai.info/renaming-android-manifest-package/):

> It's easy to fix though, by retrieving the package name of another
>   resource with Resources.getResourcePackageName().
>
> Let's create a resource id dedicated to that purpose, for example in
>   res/values/ids.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item name="used_for_package_name_retrieval" type="id"/>
</resources>
```

> And now we get the right package:

```
Resources res = context.getResources();
String packageName = res.getResourcePackageName(R.id.used_for_package_name_retrieval);
int id = res.getIdentifier("some_drawable", "drawable", packageName);
```

Comment: I don't understand this implementation, wouldn't you need to know the package of R in order to import it to the java file? If not you cannot compile it

Answer (score 2):

I don't believe there is a method to list the package identifiers in `Resources`, but you can always use `getResourceTypeName()` with a known R value to get the package name.  Something like:

```
String packageName = res.getResourcePackageName(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
res.getIdentifier("name", "type", packageName);
```

I realize it's not ideal since it requires you to pass a known resource ID first, but it may be your only option.

Comment: http://www.piwai.info/renaming-android-manifest-package mentions that idea as well. I'm givng you an upvote, but not marking as correct since that's not what I'm after.

Comment: @HeathBorders - considering you just edited this same functionality into your own answer, don't you think you should give Devunwired the accept credit for proposing it?

Comment: I already knew about that solution, and it wasn't strictly the answer I was looking for with this question. It's a workaround. I gave him an upvote. I should maybe have added that link into my question since I already knew about it. The answer I found on google was correct. It can't be done.